# Search for all contacted domains on webcrawl in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to write a small PHP script where you deliver a domain name and a web crawler opens it. After that, the script needs to check what are the contacted domains when you open that specific page (Like Cloudflare, google Ads, and so on)

Currently, I am getting the whole content and looking for the  tag. If a CSS is present or JS I am following this and going deeper. With that, I am building a link list. Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
  echo "Crawling url: ".$url."\r\n";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom -> loadHTML($html);
$content = $dom -> getElementsByTagname('link');
foreach ($content as $item) {
    $attribute = $item->getAttribute('href');
        if(str_contains($attribute, '.css')){
            crawl_css($url."/".$attribute, curl($url."/".$attribute), 1); 
    }
```

Comment: _"If a CSS is present or JS i am following this and going deeper."_ - "going deeper" meaning what, exactly? The CSS could use a background image from a different domain, JavaScript could dynamically create script elements that load content from different domains ... you want to catch all those as well?

Comment: Yes. So i want to see actually all contacted domains when you open one specific url.

Comment: Then you probably won't get very far with PHP alone, this will rather need something like a headless browser, that will also parse/execute the CSS and JS ...

Comment: So what would you suggest then? Is it better to start all over with python?

Comment: Selenium, in combination with https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/, would probably be a good way to go.